# UIScrollView with custom horizontal scrolling

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiscrollview, ios7

I need to create an horizontal list with a scroll, this list is made of 10 images, in the screen only fits 1 and a half of these images, so when the user scroll i need to set at the center of the screen an image and besides it a portion on the forward image and backward image. So far what i have is this:

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 1024, 520)];
scroll.delegate = self;
scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
int numberOfViews = 10;
float xOrigin = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    xOrigin = i * 600;
    FigureImage *tape = [[FigureImage alloc] initCustom];
    [scroll addSubview:tape];
    FigureImage *pictureFigure = [[FigureImage alloc] initCustom];
    [scroll addSubview:pictureFigure];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfViews*10, 500);
pageWidth = (numberOfViews*10)/numberOfViews;


[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

With this code i am able to scroll the images, but the scroll doesnt stop at any particular image, how can i able the last x position to stop the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

See the delegate method `-scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`.

Its last parameter is an in-out `CGPoint` whose value you can change so that the scroll comes to rest with an image centered exactly.

Comment: Ok, how can i stop the scroll in the view i want?

Comment: From the point you are passed, work out the nearest point that centres the view  and pass that point back.